# numberposts not showing specific number

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I'm using [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) plugin to show up the specific posts from a category on a page.
It works well, but if I'm trying to reduce the number of my latest posts to 3, for example this  way:

```
[catlist id=13 numberposts=3]
```

It shows up all the posts from that category. Am I doing somwthing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `numberposts` parameter is correct. I'm using this code:

```
[catlist numberposts=10 excerpt_size=10 excerpt=yes thumbnail=yes thumbnail_class="alignright" class="lcp_catlist_clear"]
```

It's working on [this page](http://picandocodigo.net/programacion/wordpress/wordpress-sandbox/), showing the latest 10 posts. Maybe the category id is wrong?